# Reverse triangle in Python

Tags: python

Hello I wrote a program does this;

```
    * 
   * * 
  * * * 
 * * * * 
* * * * *
```

But now I want to do this ;

```
    * * * * *
     * * * *   
      * * * 
       * * 
        *
```

Here is my code, how can I modify my code to print the triangle in reverse form.

```
n = int(input("Input triangle height: "))

for var in range(0, n):
    for i in range(0, n - var - 1):
        print(end=" ")
    for i in range(0, var + 1):
        print("*", end=" ")
    print()
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: You only have to change the outer for loop. If you want the data reversed then use [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed): `for var in reversed(range(0, n)):`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just reverse the outer loop, like so:

```
n = int(input("Input triangle height: "))

for var in range(n-1, -1, -1):
    for i in range(0, n - var - 1):
        print(end=" ")
    for i in range(0, var + 1):
        print("*", end=" ")
    print()
```

The original range, `range(0, n)`, produces the sequence `0` through `n-1`.  The new range, `range(n-1, -1, -1)`, produces the sequence `n-1` through `0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input("Input triangle height: "))

for var in range(n, 0, -1):
    for i in range(n - var):
        print(end=" ")
    for i in range(2*var -1):
        print("*", end=" ")
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here You go,

```
n = int(input("Input triangle height: "))

for var in range(n-1, -1,-1):
    for i in range(0, n - var - 1):
        print(end=" ")
    for i in range(0, var + 1):
        print("*", end=" ")
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: just reverse the range

```
n = int(input("Input triangle height: "))

for var in reversed(range(0, n)): # put a reversed here
    for i in range(0, n - var - 1):
        print(end=" ")
    for i in range(0, var + 1):
        print("*", end=" ")
    print()
```

You may save the answer first,

```
n = int(input("Input triangle height: "))
lines = []
for var in range(0, n):
    lines.append("")
    for i in range(0, n - var - 1):
        lines[var] += " "
    for i in range(0, var + 1):
        lines[var] += "* "
for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

Then if you wanna reverse it, simply do,

```
n = int(input("Input triangle height: "))
lines = []
for var in range(0, n):
    lines.append("")
    for i in range(0, n - var - 1):
        lines[var] += " "
    for i in range(0, var + 1):
        lines[var] += "* "
for line in reversed(lines):
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
num = int(input("Give me the number of rows: ")) 
for i in range(0,num):
    for j in range(0, i):
        print(end = " ")
    for j in range(0, num - i):
        print("*",end = " ")
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

As said by others,

```
  1 n = int(input("Input triangle height: "))
  2 
  3 for var in range(0, n):
  4 +--  5 lines: for i in range(0, n - var - 1):
  9 
 10 print()
 11 
 12 for var in range(n-1, -1, -1):
 13 +--  5 lines: for i in range(0, n - var - 1):
```

wanted to add the output because it is pretty:

```
> python python-exec.py 
Input triangle height: 6
     * 
    * * 
   * * * 
  * * * * 
 * * * * * 
* * * * * * 

* * * * * * 
 * * * * * 
  * * * * 
   * * * 
    * * 
     *
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input("Input triangle height: "))

for var in range(n, 0, -1):
    for i in range(n - var):
        print(end=" ")
    for i in range(0,var):
        print("*", end=" ")
    print()
```

[This tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pg7i7FPUJds) explains it very well.